# In islam, is it permissible to study medicine & become a doctor?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamualaikum

I am going to join a coaching centre to inshallah become a doctor.

My questions  are:

1. Can we can become a doctor in islam
2. Is it permissible to raw (cut) human body parts or work on dead body
3. Finally,  is it ok to draw diagrams for education purpose?

Comment: Once your question has been answered you can not edit it to something totally different.

Answer (score 3):

It is permissible in Islam to become a doctor.

In general, Islam never told that a believer should abstain from studying medecine, and there are many Muslim physicians worldwide; rulings only concern some points as those you have mentioned in your question:

- You may draw and study drawings of any parts of the human body; drawings of the entire body may be acceptable if it is essential to draw the entire body for medical purposes but it should be avoided

[Reference](https://islamqa.org/?p=36353).

- It is disputed to what extent working with a dead body is allowable

[Reference declaring it permissible under certain conditions](https://islamqa.org/?p=1676)

[Reference declaring it not permissible](https://islamqa.org/?p=5671).

There are ways to study medicine and practice as a physician that conform the commandments according to to Islamic rulings. So, you need not abstain from this career for religious reasons.